# Padding based on size of string?

Tags: javascript, html, css, string, padding

I'm trying to dynamically insert some list into an `element` called `foos`. I want to manually number this list (e.g. `<span>${i + 1}. </span>` for `i` in the list element number) but I want the distance between this number and the element to align nicely. By nicely I mean:

```
 8. foo
 9. foo
10. foo
11. foo
```

rather than what is displayed in the snippet, i.e.

```
8. foo
9. foo
10. foo
11. foo
```

Thanks for any help here!

```js
let people = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
var htmlString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  var person = people[i];
  htmlString += `<span>${i + 1}. </span><span>${person}</span><br>`;
}
$('#foos').html(htmlString);
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="foos"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rely on some CSS and counter to easily achieve this:

```js
let people = ['foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
var htmlString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  htmlString += `<span>${people[i]}</span>`;
}
$('#foos').html(htmlString);
```

```css
#foos {
  counter-reset:num;
}
#foos span {
  display:block;
  margin-left:20px; /*adjust this*/
  position:relative;
}
#foos span:before {
  content:counter(num)'.';
  counter-increment:num;
  position:absolute;
  right:100%;
  margin-right:3px; /*adjust this*/
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="foos"></div>
```

If the number can increase a lot you can try the following where the width of the number area will adjust based on the maximum number:

```js
let people = ['foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'a', 'foo', 'foo bar', 'foo', 'f', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
var htmlString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  htmlString += `<span>${people[i]}</span>`;
}
$('#foos').html(htmlString);
```

```css
#foos {
  counter-reset:num;
}
#foos span {
  display:table-row;
}
#foos span:before {
  content:counter(num)'.';
  counter-increment:num;
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="foos"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, although not completely dynamic for unpredictable number of person names (needs manual tweaking of margins right?). I am wondering if there is a completely dynamic solution based on pure CSS.

Comment: @ajobi you can simply use a margin to cover 3 character it would be enough since you can have 999 names and I don't think you will have this amount of names

Comment: Yeah, I have a similar solution at the moment, although a little bit less code. It's just my curiosity that keeps looking for a true dynamic solution. With no unnecessary whitespace and so on.

Comment: This is really cool! It actually inspired me to do something similar with my approach. I will update my answer if you don't mind ;-)

Comment: @ajobi you can update your answer but they need to remain different or we will defeat the purpose of having *different* answers ;)

Comment: understood, I think I have the final update. Your counter approach makes it, I hope, enough different from what I attempted to do. I just couldn't leave it having the partially dynamic solution. Thanks for inspiration by the way, I didn't see the `counter` ever before ! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think use the following tag `<pre></pre>` would help.
`<pre>` tag keeps white spaces.

And the use of a monospaced font ensures that white spaces are same width than other characters.

Hope it helps ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be possible using CSS:

```js
let people = ['foosa', 'foo', 'foofsafa', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foofsafasf', 'foo'];
var htmlString = "";
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
  var person = people[i];
  htmlString += `
      <div class="item-wrapper">
    <span>${i + 1}. </span>
          <span>${person}</span>
      </div>`;
}
$('#foos').html(htmlString);
```

```css
.item-wrapper {
  display: table-row;
}

.item-wrapper span {
  display: table-cell;
}

.item-wrapper span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" 
    type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="foos"></div>
```

Edit inspired by the @Temani Afif's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a style to:
htmlString += `<span>${i + 1}. </span><span>${person}</span><br>`;

htmlString += `<span style="text-align:right;">${i + 1}. </span><span>${person}</span><br>`;

Answer (score 0):

Find out how much you need to pad by finding out the length of your array, then the length of the length of your array... then use the padding function.

```
var blah = ["foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo","foo"];
var textToAppend = ". ";
var padTo = (blah.length + textToAppend).length;
for(var i = 0; i<blah.length;i++)
  {
    padded = ((i+1) + textToAppend).padStart(padTo);
    console.log(padded + blah[i]);
  }
```

and get this out

```
 1. foo
 2. foo
 3. foo
 4. foo
 5. foo
 6. foo
 7. foo
 8. foo
 9. foo
10. foo
11. foo
12. foo
13. foo
14. foo
15. foo
16. foo
17. foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
let people = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
let max_string_size = (people.length + "").length;  
let htmlString = people.map((person, idx) => {
  let idx_str = (idx + 1 + "").padStart(max_string_size).replace(/\s/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  return `<span>${idx_str}. </span><span>${person}</span><br>`;
}).join("")
$('#foos').html(htmlString);
```