# Vertically align cells across html ul list items

Tags: html, css, list, html-table

What I need is a `ul` list that looks like this:

```
 - xxx      yyy
 - xxxxxxx  yy
 - xxxxx    yyyyy
```

rather than

```
 - xxx yyy
 - xxxxxxx yy
 - xxxxx yyyyy
```

So inside

```
<ul>
   <li><div class="cell1"></div><div class="cell2"></div></li>
   <li><div class="cell1"></div><div class="cell2"></div></li>
   <li><div class="cell1"></div><div class="cell2"></div></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to merge a table like alignment.

---

Update: And what about having a wrapper `div` inside the `li`?

```
<ul class="table-list">
  <li><div><span>xxx</span><span>yyy</span></div></li>
  <li><div><span>xxxxxxx</span><span>yy</span></div></li>
  <li><div><span>xxxxx</span><span>yyyyy</span></div></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d6zvLgfu/1/

Comment: you have display:table (exmaple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866150/8620333 (check the second snippet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table;` and it will behave like a table:

```css
ul.table-list {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

ul.table-list li {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}

ul.table-list span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  border: 1px solid #14cce4; /* visualize the table */
}


/* add bullet if needed */

ul.table-list li:before {
  content: "- "
}
```

```html
<ul class="table-list">
  <li><span>xxx</span><span>yyy</span></li>
  <li><span>xxxxxxx</span><span>yy</span></li>
  <li><span>xxxxx</span><span>yyyyy</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could use `div`, but `span` makes more sense in an inline context.

Comment: But it's still supposed to look like a list, isn't it?

Comment: @Johannes Please ask OP. Don't know the requirements. Looking again at the question, you might be right. But that would be a simple matter of additional styling.

Comment: I added a simple bullet for the table solution.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is what I was looking for. But now I got one more problem: for additional styling I would need to wrap the `span`s inside another div, something like `<li><div class="wrapper"><span>cell1</span><span>cell2</span></div><div class="wrapper">other stuff not in a table cell</div></li>`. I tried to add this, but it always breaks the layout

Comment: Well, the solutions offered do reflect the question, a simple text alignment. If there are design requirements, maybe it would make sense to ask a new question, including those requirements. A table is not the best choice for styling. What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: I have a `div` wrapper that works as a flex container and kind of header. Maybe I should ask a new question, but maybe there is an easy way to fix your answer to make it still work. I added my question accordingly, also created a fiddle where I tried myself

Comment: Seems like there is CSS (*"I have a div wrapper that works as a flex container and kind of header."*) that is not provided in your question.
You modified the question after accepting an answer. For other people reading that question later, things might become confusing, it is not best practice. 
Ask a new question and provide more context. Especially the CSS-styles that are applied, so that they can be considered in answers. You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We will then be able to help you way better.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make all DIVs inside `li`s inline-blocks and add percentage widths to `.cell1` and `cell2`:

```css
li>div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.cell1 {
  width: 20%;
}

.cell2 {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="cell1">dfg</div>
    <div class="cell2">oiu vdsklndsf oiu</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="cell1">tzuk</div>
    <div class="cell2">amn dfg sdflgj dflgmn voj seorgij ef,mgn dflj ldkfgm .,m dfg sdflgj dflgmn voj seorgij ef,mgn dflj ldkfgm moiudskjn dfsoiu sdfne roie n sdlkjh sdfkjb i iuerkjn kjh kdf</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="cell1">dsfoiu oisdfg</div>
    <div class="cell2">vxciuh dfsndf smn iuzg</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```